# Determining the port a Visual Studio Web App runs on

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I've been using the macro from [this blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/koenv/archive/2008/02/14/quick-attach-and-detach-debugger.aspx) for attaching the Visual Studio debugger to an already running instance of the Web Application I'm currently working on. However, if I have more than one instance of the Visual Studio web server running it's pot luck which one it'll attach to.

Is there a way to determine what port is configured in the Web project so I can modify the macro to filter its choice of process to that one?

---

Further Info

I'm aware that you can set the port number to a static one - I've done just that from the get-go, what I'm trying to determine is how to *programatically* determine the defined port-number so I can modify the macro (in the linked blog entry) and ensure it connects to the right instance of the Visual Studio web server.

The way I have things running is I have two (or more) instances of Visual Studio running, each of which contains a Solution, which contains a web project and one or more other projects - typically an Installer project), so when I trigger the macro from a given instance of Visual Studio, I want to find the Web Project within that instances loaded solution and determine the port it's running against.

Comment: I think I'm missing something obvious - I still don't understand the question. For example, are you working in two+ web applications at the same time and when you try to debug one, it attaches to another instance of Cassini instead of its own? Or are you attaching from another project?

Comment: I have multiple instances of Visual Studio loaded, I've added further clarification to the question :=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that can help you, I have found a link that might actually to the trick.

However, it require DllImport call and a lot of fun.

You can take a look at that article there: http://bytes.com/forum/thread574901.html

Quotes from the actual site:

> By calling into iphlpapi.dll using
>   PInvoke interop. Google around for
>   GetExtendedTcpTable and iphlpapi.dll,
>   I'm sure you will find some existing
>   stuff.
>
> Willy.

And one last:

> Here are some API-Methods for my
>   purposes:
>
> GetTcpTable()
>   AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack()
>   GetExtendedTcpTable()
>
> I wrote a small programm that is able
>   to show me all Processes with the
>   belonging TCP-Ports (with
>   AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack())
>   running under Windows XP.
>
> Now my problem is, that under Windows
>   2000 I can't use
>   AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack() or
>   GetExtendedTcpTable() so I'm only able
>   to use GetTcpTable() to list all
>   TCP-Ports but without the belonging
>   processes.
>
> Did somebody have the same problem or
>   is there another way (.Net or WMI
>   etc.) to solve my problem?
>
> Thanks in advance,
>
> Werner

Answer (score 2):

This code will get you a list of all ports for the projects in the current solution:

```
Sub GetWebProjectPorts()
    Dim ports As String

    For Each prj As Project In DTE.Solution.Projects
        For Each p As EnvDTE.Property In prj.Properties
            If p.Name.Contains("DevelopmentServerPort") Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ports) Then
                    ports += ","
                End If
                ports += p.Value.ToString()
            End If
        Next
    Next

    MsgBox(ports)
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the properties for your web project and look under the "Web" tab, you can specify which port the project will always start up on. Then you can click "Enable Edit and Continue" so you don't have to stop debugging and restart continuously.